# Mulitpicklist validation

Tags: validation-rule, validation

HI all I am working on a validation such that if "Other" value in a multipicklist is choosen then a text field B cannot be blank.

AND(ISPICKVAL( A__c,"Other" ), ISBLANK( B__c )). I had done it for a normal picklist but how do I modify this for a multipicklist value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `INCLUDES(Multi_Picklist, "Value 1")` for multipicklist field. For picklist we use `ISPICKVAL()` but it is not supported in Multiselect picklist

The validation rule will be as below.

```
AND(INCLUDES( A__c,"Other" ), ISBLANK( B__c )).
```

Comment: I have to add another condition such that if I choose any other option other than Value 1 then the textbox cannot be filled.